# Custom domain private email server goes directly to spam?

Tags: nginx, email, email-server

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this. Any help would be appreciated! If I am at the wrong place, a point in the correct direction would be appreciated.

I have recently set up an email server on a dedicated server with a .com and SSL certificate. It is all successfully set up with no errors and 100% ready. Any email accounts I make work, they send and receive. But any messages I send go automatically to the SPAM folder on any gmail users, and also hotmail. The SSL is throughout the entire domain and is completely encrypted. Anything I can find is about existing emails held with google or yahoo or microsoft. I can not find anything for custom domains.

(EDIT - my domain is remulated.com )

Answer (score 2):

You should set up [Sender Policy Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and [DomainKeys Identified Mail](http://www.dkim.org/). Both are done using DNS and are relatively straightforward so long as you have a decent email system. I've implemented both on Google Apps and Fastmail with no issues.

Check your server / domain aren't on email blacklists - one great tool is [MXToolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx). If they are you'll have to follow the blacklist procedures to get them off the list.

You should also set up [DMARC](https://dmarc.org/). From their website

> DMARC, which stands for “Domain-based Message Authentication,
>   Reporting & Conformance”, is an [email authentication](https://dmarc.org/wiki/Glossary#Email_Authentication) protocol. It
>   builds on the widely deployed SPF and DKIM protocols, adding a
>   reporting function that allows senders and receivers to improve and
>   monitor protection of the domain from fraudulent email.

If you edit your question to include your domain name you could get more specific advice for your situation.

Comment: I love the prompt answer! I will try this out later today. Thanks!